# Display from Dropdown selection with post

Tags: php

I found this solotion everywhere on the web but i cant figure it out why it won't work.

So i have this drop-down

```
<select name="gender">
  <option value="">Choose Gender</option>
  <option value="1" name="male">Male</option>
  <option value="2" name="female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Then i have the following php code

```
if (isset($_POST['gender']) === 1){
   echo 'Gender: Male <br /> ';
}else if (isset($_POST['gender']) === 2){
   echo 'Gender: Female <br /> ';
}else{
   echo 'Gender: Not Set <br /> ';
}
```

And all i get from the output is

> Gender: Not Set

Sooo what am i missing here?

p.s im a newbie. Be gentle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, `isset()` returns a `bool`, not the value being tested.  (Note the semantics of "is set", which is a yes/no concept.)  Additionally, `===` also compares types and I suspect all posted values are strings by default.  Remove the `isset()` calls and use a less-strict comparison:

```
if ($_POST['gender'] == 1){
    echo 'Gender: Male <br /> ';
}else if ($_POST['gender'] == 2){
   echo 'Gender: Female <br /> ';
}else{
   echo 'Gender: Not Set <br /> ';
}
```

If you do want to use `isset()` to check the existence of the value at all before examining the value, you can wrap the whole thing in that condition:

```
if (isset($_POST['gender'])){
    if ($_POST['gender'] == 1){
        echo 'Gender: Male <br /> ';
    }else if ($_POST['gender'] == 2){
       echo 'Gender: Female <br /> ';
    }else{
       echo 'Gender: Not Set <br /> ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay i would have never guessed that. But yeah that make sense...now. Thank you.